# compiling vmd throws error: ld cant find tcl8.5

Tags: compilation, tcl, ld, vmd

While compiling VMD-1.92 from source, compiling plugins section gives error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl8.5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Reaping losing child 0x2094ac0 PID 10626 
Makefile:49: recipe for target '../compile/lib_LINUXAMD64/bin/catdcd5.1/catdcd' failed
make[2]: *** [../compile/lib_LINUXAMD64/bin/catdcd5.1/catdcd] Error 1
Removing child 0x2094ac0 PID 10626 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x1ea5520 PID 10616 
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'bins' failed
make[1]: *** [bins] Error 1
Removing child 0x1ea5520 PID 10616 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x1262ed0 PID 10432 
Make-arch:402: recipe for target 'LINUXAMD64' failed
make: *** [LINUXAMD64] Error 2
Removing child 0x1262ed0 PID 10432 from chain.
```

I have tcl8.6 installed. I have exhausted all avenues to solve the issue. Can someone please advise.

thanks

Comment: It's trying to link against 8.5 (a currently supported version) so maybe install that? It's perfectly OK to have both 8.5 and 8.6 installed on the same system.

Comment: Do you really need to compile the VMD? It is much faster to use the binary package.

Comment: UNFORTUNATELY, I THOUGHT I DID. IT HAD BEEN SO LONG SINCE I HAD ORIGINALLY INSTALLED VMD I FORGOT THAT THE LAST TIME I HAD THE SAME PROBLEM, AND FOUND THE BINARY DITRO AND USED THAT WITH SUCCESS. SORRY FOR SUCH A LONG DELAY IN ANSWER I LOST MY WAY BACK HERE.